# Работа phpmyadmin и unicron - одновременно?

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, gunicorn

```
server { 
 listen 80 default_server; 
server_name test_domain  www.test_domain; 
root /var/www/test_domain;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   # include proxy_params;
   # proxy_pass http://unix:/home/test/flask_api/myproject.sock;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
 }

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location /app {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/test/flask_api/myproject.sock;
}


}
```

Я хочу, что бы по адресу `http://192.168.120.137/phpmyadmin` - отрывалась админ панель, а по адресу `http://192.168.120.137/app` - срабатывал unicorn - вызывая мой python-скрипт (flask). Проблема в том, что перенаправление на unicron - срабатывает, если я по корневому пути - `/` - прописываю `proxy_pass`, но  тогда это ломает мне доступ к phpmyadmin. Попытался прописать еще один путь - `location /app` , ео получаю 404 ? Как правильно настроить nginx в данном случае ?

### UPD

Все же расскоментировал

```
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/test/flask_api/myproject.sock;
```

- в корневом пути и добавил `/` - в конце - т.е. вот так: `proxy_pass http://unix:/home/test/flask_api/myproject.sock/;` - что бы перенаправляло по остаточному пути, после myproject.sock, если там 404 - но теперь получаю 502 от ohomyadmin

### UPD 2

Изменил маршрут во Flask:

```
@app.route("/app")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"
```

конфиг nginx:

```
server { 
 listen 80 default_server; 
server_name test_domain  www.test_domain; 
root /var/www/test_domain;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   # include proxy_params;
   # proxy_pass http://unix:/home/test/flask_api/myproject.sock;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
 }

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location /app {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/test/flask_api/myproject.sock;
}


}
```

После каждого изменения файла конфигурации ил python-скрипта - перезапускаю службы:

```
sudo systemctl restart flask_api.service && sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

, но все равно, по маршруту `http://192.168.120.137/app/` - получаю 404 (проблемы с phpmyadmin - исчезли)

Вызов - `sudo systemctl status flask_api.service` - показывает, что сервис работает

`/var/log/nginx/error.log` - пустой (до этого удалял файл, что бы посмотреть, какие ошибки сыпятся)

`/var/log/nginx/access.log` - просто показывает 404 со второй машины - откуда обращаюсь

Comment: Если вы хотите работать с путём /app, то переделайте настройки роутинга в вашем фласке так, чтобы он умел обрабатывать этот самый /app

Comment: Добавление `/` в конце не прокатит, если ваш фласк будет генерировать какие-то ссылки - чтобы ссылки сгенерировались правильные, он должен знать про существование этого самого /app. Поэтому даже если решение рабочее - оно может оказаться неправильным, а самое правильное - переделать роутинг во фласке

Comment: А 502 намекает на то, что у вас php-fpm недоступен, подробности смотрите в логе ошибок nginx

Comment: `/app` и `/app/` это разные ссылки, и если фласк не настроен на обработку `/app/`, то это нормально, что он ничего не обрабатывает и возвращает 404.

Comment: ахахах, спасибо! я не обратил внимания - час убил на это..... Еще раз - спасибо)